# CalendarView to setMinDate to setMaxDate

Tags: java, android

Trying to solve this for whole day, but couldn't solve the issue.

What i want is to set the min and max to Calendar view to current month and year with all days.

So user can't scroll to previous month or next month.

What i tried so far is :

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int minMonthCalendarView = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1;
    int maxMonthCalendarView = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 2;

    technicianDateHint.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Your) + " " + String.valueOf(currentDay) + "-" +
            String.valueOf(currentMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(currentYear));

    try {
        date = DDMMMYYYY.parse(item.getDueDate());
        item.setDueDate(DDMMYYY.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    userDate.setText(item.getDueDate());
    technicianDate.setShowWeekNumber(false);
    technicianDate.setMinDate(minMonthCalendarView);
    technicianDate.setMaxDate(maxMonthCalendarView);
    technicianDate.setUnfocusedMonthDateColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    technicianDate.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int day) {
            technicianDateHint.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);

        }
    });
```

> int minMonthCalendarView = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1;
>       int maxMonthCalendarView = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 2;

When set with minDate without maxDate it's works fine. Since user can't scroll to previous month but can to next month.

Is there any way to setMinDate and setMaxDate to current month ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);//not sure this is needed
 long endOfMonth = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
 //may need to reinitialize calendar, not sure
 calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
 long startOfMonth = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
 calendarView.setMaxDate(endOfMonth);
 calendarView.setMinDate(startOfMonth);
```

Comment: A small change in initialization on calendar.
 private Calendar calendarStart;
 private Calendar calendarEnd;
Works perfect, Thanks Mate....Matt